# What is the literal meaning of this regex that contains a lookahead?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to understand the positive and negative lookahead, but I think I'm missing something.

```
q(?=u)
```

What I understand this regex to mean is: "match a q that is followed by a u", so I get a match with the string "quit", but getting only  a group with 'q'.

But with the regex q(?=u)i, I don't get any result with the string "quit". Why does happen? Probably this regex doesn't have sense, but I would like to know what it means in order to understand the lookahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookahead doesn't consume its text.  `qu` is different from `q(?=u)` -- the latter matches just a `q`, but requires it to be followed by `u` (which is however not captured or consumed).

And that's why `q(?=u)i` cannot match -- the `q` needs to be followed by `u` *and* `i` at the same time, which is impossible.  In other words, it would find and capture `qi` but only if the `q` was immediately followed by `u` which is obviously not true if it is followed by `i`.

If you want to match `qui`, the regex for that is `qui`.

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else. When explaining character classes, this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a q not followed by a u. Negative lookahead provides the solution: q(?!u). The negative lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial regex u.

Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)